# Asking a question about an app

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Are there any Stack Exchange sites where I can ask a question about an app or about finding an app that does a specific thing?

For example - if I want to know if there are any good scientific calculator apps on the Microsoft store - where can I ask such a question?

Comment: As a new contributor I have a request: I like receiving feedback - both positive and negative. However, if you vote down and don't tell me why, it is wasting your vote because it is nothing I can change. So, please help me and give me direction when you click the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there any Stack Exchange sites where I can ask a question about an app [...]

[Super User](//superuser.com)

> [...] or about finding an app that does a specific thing?
>
> [...]

[Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

> [...]
>
> For example - if I want to know if there are any good scientific calculator apps on the Microsoft store - where can I ask such a question?

[Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)